# Why is a fill of 0xFFFFFFFF transparent?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Why is it that the following code draws the rectangle fully transparent?

```
graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFFFF);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
graphics.endFill();
```

I'm aware that beginFill takes an argument without alpha, i.e. 0xRRGGBB, but having an alpha works for any color other than full white. It works fine for 0xFFFFFFFE for example.
For full white you have to AND with 0x00FFFFFF everywhere which is annoying.

Is there a logical reason for this behavior?

Comment: using 0xAARRGGBB format doesn't "*work*", unless by "*work*" you mean "the alpha gets ignored". If this is really killing you, then just make a static helper to do this for you: `function(g:Graphics, c:uint):void { g.beginFill(c&0xFFFFFF, (c >> 24)/255); };`. As to *why* I think @Lucero's answer is probably the best you'll get.

Comment: @32bitkid Yes, that's what I meant. The alpha gets ignored. In my case, all the color values had full alpha so I didn't notice at first. I still think it's a weird inconsistency though. At least now there's a hit on google for the problem if anyone else has it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input value is expected to be 0x00RRGGBB, then passing in a value >= 0x01000000 is just not valid input. Probably this was hacked into the code to skip the fill if someone passes in the constant value for transparent.

Comment: In Flex, this value is defined as StyleManager.NOT_A_COLOR.  Since Stylemanager is not available in Flash, presumably someone has copied the idea without a place to put a color (or the Flex team formalized it). Take heart, this value doesn't work everywhere :)